# How to embed the same redux-form multiple times on a page?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm having an issue trying to embed multiple forms on one page. I noticed `configForm` executes once, even with multiple forms on the page, that's why I can't dynamically generate different form names.

[Screenshot showing multiple text fields bound together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vfwN.png).

```js
function configForm(){
  const uuid = UUID.generate();

  const config = {
    form:`AddCardForm_${uuid}`,
    fields:['text'],
    validate:validate
  }

  return config;
}

export default reduxForm(configForm(), mapStateToProps, {togglePanelEditMode, addCardToPanel})(CardFormContainer);
```

How can I add the forms so that they behave independent of each other?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There are two ways to embed the same form multiple times on the page.

**1. Using `formKey` (Redux Form 5)**

`formKey` is the official way of doing this when using `redux-form@5` (or below). You have to pass the key from the parent to identify the form:

```js
panels.map(panel =>
  <PanelForm key={panel.uuid} formKey={panel.uuid} initialValues={panel} />
                              ^^^^^^^ 
                       declare the form key
)
```

Your form definition would be:

```js
reduxForm({form: "AddCardForm", fields: ["text"], validate})
```

However this pattern has been removed from `redux-form@6`.

**2. Using a unique `form` name (Redux Form 5 and above)**

The following pattern is the recommended way of identifying forms since Redux Form 6. It is fully compatible with previous versions.

```js
panels.map(panel =>
  <PanelForm key={panel.uuid} form={`AddCardForm_${panel.uuid}`} initialValues={panel} />
                              ^^^^ 
                    declare the form identifier
)
```

Your form definition would be:

```js
reduxForm({fields: ["text"], validate})
// No `form` config parameter here!
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Very nearly asked this question again ... wish it came up in my web searches!!

Comment: Thanks. The version info in two options could be clarified a bit. My suggestion: 1. ... (Redux Form 5), 2. ... (Redux Form 6+)

Comment: I noticed that you wrote that the >5 pattern is recommended. This great answer solved a problem I was having, but never saw this in the docs anywhere. Where did you see it?

Comment: I don't remember. The doc says _`form`: the name of your form and the key to where your form's state will be mounted under the redux-form reducer_. Since you don't want to share the same data, that's the way to go. See https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1200#issuecomment-231741044

Comment: Wow this was killing me for months. I always suspected this, but docs never stated so I always thought the way we are supposed to do things is put `form` only in the `reduxForm({form:'blah'})(MyFormComponent)` line. Absolutely killed me. How come this is not documented. And why even bother documenting the bad way. React is about reusable components, the form is reusable, but with `reduxForm({form:'blah'})()` method it becomes not reusable correct? So misleading - http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/#-code-form-string-code-required - it should note the conseuqnece of no reusabilty

Comment: @Florent What if we need to connect each form to state via formValueSelector? I've created a separate question for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56635325/multiple-redux-form-with-formvalueselector