# form & initialValues properties not recognized with multiple forms in one component (redux-form v7.0.4)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm creating multiple forms within a single component and to initialize them with the redux store I'm defining the form's *name* attribute in the`<form>` element, as opposed to within the `reduxForm()` helper, which was documented here...

[How to embed the same redux-form multiple times on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456526/how-to-embed-the-same-redux-form-multiple-times-on-a-page/37464048#37464048)

I'm creating the forms from the 'listing' object and passing it to my components with `mapStateToProps()`. I'm trying to set the initial values of the form with `initialValues={}`, but Redux Form is producing the following errors and is asking for the form to be declared in the `reduxForm()` helper...

1) Failed prop type: The prop `form` is marked as required in `Form(ItemInfo)`, but its value is `undefined`.

2) Unknown prop `initialValues` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element.

And this appears to be similar to the issue mentioned here...

https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/28

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../../actions';
import {Col} from 'react-grid-system';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

class ItemInfo extends Component {

  renderSingleItem(item){
    let theItem =  _.map(_.omit(item, '_id'), (value,field) => {
        return (
          <div key={field}>
            <label>{field}</label>
            <Field component="input" type="text" name={field} style={{ marginBottom: '5px' }} />
            <div className="red-text" style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });
    return theItem || <div></div>;
  }

  renderItemInfo() {

      if (this.props.listing.listing !== undefined) {
        let theItems = _.map(this.props.listing.listing.items, item => {                
            return (
                <Col key={item._id} md={3}>
                  <form form={`editItemInfo_${item._id}`} initialValues={item}>
                    {this.renderSingleItem(item)}
                    <RaisedButton secondary={true} label="Remove Item"/>
                    <RaisedButton primary={true} label="Update Item"/>
                  </form>
                </Col>
            );
        });
        return theItems || <div></div>;
      }

  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            {this.renderItemInfo()}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({listing}) {
  return { listing };
}

ItemInfo = reduxForm({
  fields: ["text"],
  enableReinitialize: true
})(ItemInfo)

ItemInfo = connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(ItemInfo)

export default ItemInfo
```

This is an example of the 'listing' object being returned...

```
{ _id: 59b5eebd33a3a833b6ac1386,
  _user: 59aff09a11011f0cfd8d7666,
  location: 'nother',
  availability: 'jhkvljh',
  price: 9860,
  __v: 0,
  items:
   [ { equipmentType: 'kbj;kj',
       make: ';jb',
       model: ';;jb',
       watts: 9860,
       bulb: 'kjbkj',
       condition: 'kjbkjb',
       _id: 59b5eebd33a3a833b6ac1387 },
     { condition: 'houy',
       bulb: 'jhg',
       watts: 8907,
       model: 'mode',
       make: 'maker',
       equipmentType: 'smoquip',
       _id: 59b5f9cf13b37234ed033a75 } ] }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured out a work-around with a little hack. It appears that this is one part a bug with Redux Form and one part error with my initial implementation.

**Correct Implementation**

As detailed by @erikras, Redux Form creator... 
[image]
https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/28

The form config parameter needs to be passed to a decorated component and not to a jsx `<form>` component. To do this I refactored my form into an imported child component and mapped over these instead...

```
 renderItemForms() {
    if (this.props.listing.listing !== undefined) {
      return _.map(this.props.listing.listing.items, item => {
          return (
            <ItemInfo form={`editItemInfo_${item._id}`} initialValues={item} key={item._id} item={item} /> 
          );
      });
    }
  }
```

**Redux Form Bug**

The above implementation will connect your forms to the redux store properly, but it will still create a *'Failed prop type: The prop form is marked as required'* error that will break your views. The solution I found is to stick any random string in the 'form' property of the `redux-form` options to prevent the error...

```
ItemInfo = reduxForm({
  form: 'any random string here',
  fields: ["text"],
  enableReinitialize: true
})(ItemInfo)
```

The second error message for `initialValues` was only subsequent to the first 'form parameter' error so now everything is error free and in Redux dev tools I can confirm that the in-line form property is overriding the property from `reduxForm()` options. Forms are now successfully being managed by the redux store with the correct 'form name/id'...

[image]

I hope this helps save someone else a headache minor. Please excuse any incorrect terminology in my explanation above, I'm still a Redux/React noob, but if anyone want more details Im happy to provide more details on my implementation.