# Redux Form multiple forms in single page

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, multiple-forms

I have a lot of Fields on one page. They are related to different subjects and will be sent through different API. In some cases, I have fields with the same name(few instance of the same object - will sent through single API twice). The **form** can be just string type. How to implement multiple forms through Redux form https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/? Does anyone have the same issue?

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'simple' // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm)
```

Comment: You will need to pass a unique form name as props. Have a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456526/how-to-embed-the-same-redux-form-multiple-times-on-a-page/37464048

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed the same redux-form multiple times on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456526/how-to-embed-the-same-redux-form-multiple-times-on-a-page)