# React Redux Form (Multiple Forms) - Routing & State Handling Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-thunk

I am building a SPA using React. I have different forms on different routes. I am using Redux Form for building & maintaining the state of the form. I have components and most of them have a form. In `reduxForm()` I am using the `form` property to provide a unique name to form. Here is a code of a form.

```
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  reduxForm({ form: 'doctor' })
)(Doctor);
```

I had around 3 forms at moment with a different value for `form` property for different components.

Here is my code for root reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import { USER_LOGOUT } from '../actions/types';
import auth from './auth';
import doctor from './doctor';
import patient from './patient';
import consultation from './consultation';

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  auth,
  doctor,
  patient,
  consultation,
  form: formReducer
});
```

Now if I use such code then the routing does not work properly. As I click on the first form following warning is thrown.

[image: Warning on First Form Click]

However, as soon as I switch to another form in my route then the React throws the following error in console and screen becomes blank.

[image: Warning on Second Form Click]

[image: Error1 on Second Form Click]

[image: Error2 on Second Form Click]

[image: Error3 on Second Form Click]

It is also interesting to notice that the `prop` `form` of the second form component props does not change. Its registered fields remain the same as that of the previous form.

[image: Second Form <code>form</code> prop]

However, If I change the name of the property in my root reducers from `form: formReducer` to something say `forms: formReducer` then routing work perfectly but I am not able to change the value of any input in the form, in other words, the state is not bound to the input. So, basically what I get that there is some issue with `ReduxForm`. It is also noticed that now we have two props `form` and `forms`. In `form` you get the name of the selected form and in `forms` you get its fields.

[image: Changed Props]

Here is the code of my `index.js` file in case you need it.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppContainer>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Welcome} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={App} />
        <Route path="/patientreg" component={Patient} />
        <Route path="/doctorreg" component={Doctor} />
        <Route path="/consultation" component={Consultation} />
        <Route path="/signout" component={Signout} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
      </AppContainer>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

I will really appreciate if you help me to figure out the issue. I am stuck at the moment. I have spent a quite long time researching the cause and had gone through various forums & SO post but of no use.

Here are some links I have gone through which can be useful to you

[Github: ReduxForm Issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1906)

[Stack Overflow Same Redux-form multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456526/how-to-embed-the-same-redux-form-multiple-times-on-a-page/37464048#37464048)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after wasting hours I found out the answer. The reason for I was getting a blank screen was due to `Object Object` in `form` field of the props. Due to this, there is a problem in unmounting the component. This happens because the arguments are passed in the wrong order in `compose()`. As the FAQ ([How do I mapStateToProps or mapDispatchToProps?](https://redux-form.com/7.2.2/docs/faq/howtoconnect.md/)) of redux form clearly shows that you first need to apply `connect()` & then you should pass the modified component to `reduxForm()`

So I just updated my last line of the component as

```
export default compose(
  reduxForm({ form: 'doctor', key: 'doctor'  }),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(Doctor);
```

Note that I also included key `prop` that is because in future I want to initialize my form with some prefetch values from the api which should happen properly. Kindly see the issue [Dynamic form names - Redux form state not updating when changing forms](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2886)

**Caution**

I still had to figure what will happen when I initialize the form with initial value because of the given issue ([Get InitialValues by connecting mapStateToProps](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3491)) in redux form repo on github. Here the order of arguments `connect()` & `reduxForm()` in the `compose()` is reversed. I will update once I reach that section.